# how to programmatically set good scan beep on zebra device(Zebra MC3300) (only beep when specific type of barcode is scanned) using android kotlin app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, audio, barcode-scanner

I want my scanner to beep only when the barcode with "/" is scanned, what I have done is my app check if the barcode scanned have "/" but the beep is produced first then app check if the scanned barcode is right or not

Comment: Are you using the `DataWedge` or `EMDK` for the scanner api?

Comment: DataWedge scanner api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to mute the scanner beep and then have your app generate the sound itself.

If you are using DataWedge the easiest way to mute the scanner beep is to replace the "Decode Audio Feedback" with a silent audio file, https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/11-1/guide/input/barcode/#scanparams.

If you are using EMDK, you should be able to set the DecodeAudioFeedbackMode to None, https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/11-0/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/ScannerConfig.DecodeAudioFeedbackMode.html.